# What is the work around for cPanel to get a valid value from $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, cpanel

I am logging server side data in laravel 5.3 platform:

```
public static function getData(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ...
        'SERVER_ADDR' => $request->server( array_key_exists('SERVER_ADDR',$_SERVER) ? 'SERVER_ADDR' : 'LOCAL_ADDR' ),
        ...
    ];
}
```

But every time I have got a empty value in return.

If there is any work around to cPanel, Please help me out.